# Conditional formatting using Hour values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a Conditional Formatting formula to be applied along two columns comparing **HOUR** values. As an example I have below three rows of the spreadsheet (the link to the actual spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EDSXrRTslKc49jRD_yX8Wd4mYbefOprcWSxnHjhXgVM/edit?usp=sharing)):

```
   |     A     |     B    |    C    |   D    |
1  |   14:00   |   02:00  |  12:00  |  12:00 | 
2  |   15:30   |   16:30  |  01:00  |  01:00 |
3  |   08:30   |   09:30  |  01:00  |  01:00 |
```

Step 1: The **C** column is a result of a **subtraction**: B - A. Since I am working with Hour values (not Date and Hour nor Date, only Hour) there is a formula that I use on the C column that is:

```
      =(B1-A1) + IF(B1 < A1; 1)
```

This formula essentially calculates B - A and if B is "smaller" than A (it actually is a timespan from the next day), it adds `1`, otherwise my result would be a negative amount of hours. (More about that [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/rwVHebffWiU).)

Step 2: The **D** column is an inserted value (not the result of any formula), and the whole column has the format (Hour).

Step 3: I created a Conditional Formatting rule that compares the values on the **C** column with the values on the **D** column. If they are different, the cells on the **C** column should be painted green:

```
=C1<>D1 on the interval C1:C1000
```

Step Problem:

The **C1** cell isn't painted, since its value is the same of the **D1** (both are `12:00`).
The **C2** also isn't painted since its value is the same of the **D2** (both are `01:00`).
The **C3 is painted** even though its value (`01:00`) is the same of the **D3** (`01:00`)!

And that behavior just goes on repeating itself apparently randomly on the spreadsheet.

I've researched a lot about it and even tested it on Excel and found that there it works like a charm. But in Google Spreadsheets I get this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is a result Google Sheets' treatment of [floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/1373663) errors (you could argue that Excel, in this respect, does the job better, as it will more often mask these errors).

You can see what is going on by changing the format of columns C and D to Number, and increase the number of displayed decimal places to about 16 (using the `.00->` button), where you will see the discrepancy.

The workaround is to perform some rounding on the calculated data, which is easier said than done. If column D only contains times containing whole minutes, you could use:

`=ROUND((B1-A1+IF(B1<A1;1))*1440)/1440`

which incidentally can be shortened to

`=ROUND(MOD(B1-A1;1)*1440)/1440`

Answer (score 2):

Very confusing but fortunately very easy to fix (I think!). Please try:

```
=round(D1;14)<>round(C1;14)
```

instead of just `=D1<>C1`.

Comment: An equally valid answer to mine, and probably much easier to implement.

Comment: Although, might be slightly safer: `=FLOOR(D1;0,00000000001)<>FLOOR(C1;0,00000000001)` to cater for edge case where one rounds up and the other down (which, perhaps, mathematically may never happen).

Comment: Pnuts your solution worked too but i can only mark one awnser as correct. Thank you guys.